# Magento website copied to new server, redirects to old

Tags: php, magento, webserver

I’ve copied whole magento site(application and database dump) on new server, where we use new address. 
But when I press the new address in the browser it redirects to the old site.

I’ve changed secure and unsecure url in core_config_data on new server to point to new address. 
I’ve deleted everything from the cache manually.

If I comment index.php not to run Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType); and just echo something, it is shown correctly in browser. 
But if I uncomment Mage::run than it redirects to the old address.

Also it doesn’t read local.xml from this new location at all, because If I just put some random data in it, 
I don’t get any error and it still redirects to new address.

Does anyone have an idea what might be the problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: Are you really sure that magento/var/cache is empty at all? If you already changed the URL in your database (and local.xml to read it), there's nothing wrong. Make sure that you are changing all configurations for URL, look for `SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path like 'web/%'`

Comment: Are you trying to go to the home page or a different page? If a different page you may need to reindex the catalog url rewrites

Answer (score 2):

You can try running the following quer(ies) against your new server's MySQL db first:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='http://new.websiteurl.com/' WHERE `value`='http://old.websiteurl.com/' LIMIT 2;
```

if you have an HTTPS url:

```
UPDATE `core_config_data` SET `value`='https://new.websiteurl.com/' WHERE `value`='https://old.websiteurl.com/' LIMIT 1;
```

Then reindex (System > Index Management) and flush magento cache storage (System > Cache Management).

Answer (score 2):

I did the `core_config_data` updates and refreshed the cache and index, the admin panel works fine but the main site `index.php` is redirecting back and forth between the old and the new.

There is now a redirect loop.  It eventually gives, "`This webpage has a redirect loop`."